# Is there a way I can send a NULL value to a SQL stored proc through XML?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005, null

I'm wondering if there is a way I can send a NULL or DBNull.Value from my C# data service to a stored proc through some configuration xml parameter.

In the proc, I want to pull some values out of the xml as a bit but because the UI allows for a third state, the bit value coming in from the xml can be NULL in which case I want to ignore any SQL updates for that field.

```
        XElement xml = new XElement("XML");
        xml.Add(new XElement("SomeConfigValue", NULL));
```

It seems when I throw a NULL into the xml from the C#, it defaults to a node with no value.

```
<SomeConfigValue />
```

When I try to grab the value from the xml as a bit in the SQL the value is interpreted as a 0.

```
select isnull(@Configuration.value('/Configuration[1]/SomeConfigValue [1]', 'bit'), NULL)
```

That's all fine and good. It makes sense. I'm just curious if anyone can suggest ideas from which I can get this to work the way I'd like it to. Perhaps I can't rely on the SQL bit type but I am currently re-factoring to be strongly typed.

I'd like to be able to grab a NULL if the value coming in isn't a 1 or 0.

```
set @SomeConfigValue = isnull(@Configuration.value('/Configuration[1]/SomeConfigValue [1]', 'bit'), NULL)
```

The goal is to ignore updating that value if it is NULL, or not a 1 or 0 in this specific SQL bit type case.

```
        update MyTable
    set ConfigValue = 
            case 
       when @SomeConfigValue IS NULL then T.SomeConfigValue
       else @SomeConfigValue 
    end from SomeTable T
```

Comment: Should there not be a standard on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the methodic used by standard xml serialization - [IsNullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable.aspx). XElement does not have similar property, but you can add attribute "xsi:nil" by yourself, and test against it in the stored proc.

Comment: Are you suggesting I do something like this?

xml.Element("NotificationId").Add(new XAttribute("xsi:nil", true));

I'm not sure if I would have to follow the standard for the name of that attribute but I am getting an exception indicating that I cannot use a colon in an attribute name.

Comment: This is because 'xsi' is namespace and only 'nil' is attribute name. Read more - http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_nil

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out

http://blogs.msdn.com/denisruc/archive/2006/11/30/xsi-nil-magic-part-1-2.aspx

and

http://blogs.msdn.com/denisruc/archive/2006/12/04/xsi-nil-magic-part-2-2.aspx

which talk about xsi:nil magic in SQL Server 2005